# I try to pass the data within the welcome.blade but "Cannot use positional argument after named argument"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am trying to pass the data to the welcome.blade but it gives this error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJLVD.png)

is there a certain syntax in laravel 8 or it's missing some package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
return view('welcome', compact('data'));
```

Comment: Yes it worked thank you.

but can you correct me if there is another syntax error when I call it in welcome page

I have tried this
<p>{{$name}}</p>

name is an index of data = $data['name']

Answer (score 1):

I think you have three ways to pass data to view in laravel 8

1-using the compact method:

```
return view('welcome', compact('data'));
```

2-using the with method:

```
return view('welcome')->with('data', $data);
```

3-parsing the data directly like this:

```
return view('welcome', ["data"=>$data]);
```

Comment: Yes but the problem now is how to call it inside <p></p> within the welcome page I have tried this:  <p>{{$name}}</p> 

the $name is the key of $data=['name']

do you have any clue

Comment: @SherifNasser try : <p>{{$data['name']}} </p> and your array defintion is wrong.define the array like this : $data = array();